# Setting object variables with a switch statement

Tags: java

Currently coding my final which is a text based adventure game. I'm having trouble initiating the character selection. My intention was to create the object of myCharacter and then fill the variables with a method in my character class. I wanted to use the while loop to avoid initializing the game before a character was set and h1 put's the character in the first room to start the game. Instead the variables never set and it's just a perpetual loop.

```
//Select Player
    while (myCharacter.HP == 0)
    {
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Select your Character\nDerek\nEmily\nMichael");
    switch (input)
    {
        case "Derek" :
        myCharacter.SetVariables("Derek", "", 100, 50, false,
        false, false, false, false, 0, h1);
        break;
        case "Emily" :

        myCharacter.SetVariables("Emily", "", 150, 20, false,
        false, false, false, false, 0, h1);
        break;

        case "Michael" :

        myCharacter.SetVariables("Michael", "", 75, 75, false,
        false, false, false, false, 0, h1);
        break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a given name");
    }
    }
```

and this is my character class with the method to set the variables.

```
class Character
{
String Name;
String Description;
int HP;
int attack;

//inventory
boolean mainKey = false;
boolean H1toH2 = false;
boolean knife = false;
boolean gasMask = false;
boolean gasMaskUse = false;
int bandage = 0;
Room currentRoom;

public void SetVariables(String N, String D, int H, int A, boolean MK,
        boolean DK, boolean K, boolean GM, boolean GMU, int B, Room CR)
    {
    N = Name;
    D = Description;
    H = HP;
    A = attack;
    MK = mainKey;
    DK = H1toH2;
    K = knife;
    GM = gasMask;
    GMU = gasMaskUse;
    B = bandage;
    CR = currentRoom;
    }
}
```

I haven't had the greatest teacher for this intro class. A lot of us are struggling with it so I've turned to youtube and reading a lot of the book.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3):

You should assign the parameter to the class fields, not conversely：

```
public void SetVariables(String N, String D, int H, int A, boolean MK,
        boolean DK, boolean K, boolean GM, boolean GMU, int B, Room CR)
{
    Name = N;
    Description = D;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names are backwards.

Should be `this.Name = N;`, for example. Using `this` will help you to understand / identity what you're actually doing. Setting "this class's fields to the values".

Also, Java variable/method naming conventions state you should not use starting capital letters for anything but classes or interfaces

Its also encouraged to use individual setter methods per value rather than making others read and figure out what unnamed parameters you're setting